# AWS elastic beanstalk, apis, and subdomains. How do I set my backend api to be a subdomain of my front end url and secure it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, subdomain, cname, a-records

I have a url that points to a s3 hosted angular application. at `example.com`

That works fine and its running under https

now I want to take my django powered API and running on elastic beanstalk and make it work as a subdomain called `api` of my `example.com` website.

So to get to the backend they type `api.example.com`

the domain is registerd with godaddy.

There I have CNAMES for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com

now for the subdomain I can't do a A record because I don't have the IP address of the elastic beanstalk instance.

Cant do the CNAME way as it was giving me an error. When I put the elasticbeanstalk url in the points to field

http://example-env.eba-thingy.somereigion.elasticbeanstalk.com

I get an error that says: `Enter either @ or a valid host name such as: "subdomain.domain.tld"`

CNAMES A Names Subdomains its all so foreign. What do I need to do to handle this correctly?

I also tried the subdomains form with no success

[image]

Comment: Have you tried regular CNAME record as shown [here](https://au.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236). With host of `api` which points to your EB url?

Comment: Make sure you leave off the `http://` when you put the value for the CNAME. The error message is showing you the format it expects for the host name.

Comment: @Marcin I did and. I get the same error as above `Enter either @ or a valid host name such as: "subdomain.domian.tld" are you suggesting I enter `api` in the `host` and the `eburl` in the `points to` field? Or is there another step?

Comment: Make sure to remove `http://` from the target when using a CNAME. You have to provide an FQDN and not a URL when creating CNAMES. If you want to get an A record using another FQDN as the target that would be CNAME flattening (you create a CNAME in your DNS and get an A record out of it). This is not supported by all DNS as it is a non-standard feature. You could move your NS to a service that supports such a feature if Godaddy doesn't. Route53 would be the logical one but it is not free, you could try Cloudflare should you want to use a free service.